# No respeta valores de mi Base de Datos

Tags: php, html, select2

Tengo un problema esta es una parte de mi formulario para editar, en mi código utilizo select para realizar un catalogo pero a la hora de editar cualquier campo y guardarlo toma la primera opción del select. ¿Como le hago para que respete los datos del select que previamente se habían ingresado y al guardar respete esos campos?

```
    <h2> Administración de equipos registrados</h2> 
    <div class="well well-small">
    <hr class="soft"/>
    <h4>Edición de equipos</h4>
    <div class="row-fluid">

    <?php
    extract($_GET);
    require("connect_db.php");

    $sql="SELECT * FROM equipos WHERE ID=$ID";
//la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
    $ressql=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row ($ressql)){
            $ID=$row[0];
            $etiqueta_equipo=$row[1];
            $departamento=$row[2];
            $id_estatus=$row[3];
            $id_tipo_equipo=$row[4];
            $id_estado_equipo=$row[5];
            $observaciones=$row[6];
            $marca=$row[7];
            $modelo=$row[8];
            $caracteristicas=$row[9];
            $ip_equipo=$row[10];
            $identificador=$row[11];
        }



    ?>



    <form action="ejecutaactualizar_equipos.php" method="post">
            Id<br><input type="text" name="ID" value= "<?php echo $ID?>" readonly="readonly"><br>
            Etiqueta del equipo<br> <input type="text" name="etiqueta_equipo" value="<?php echo $etiqueta_equipo?>"><br>
            Departamento<br> <input type="text" name="departamento" value="<?php echo $departamento?>"><br>
            Estatus<br> <select   name="id_estatus" value="<?php echo $id_estatus?>">
            <option value="Entregado">Entregado</option> 
             <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
              <option value="Resguardo">Resguardo</option>
               <option value="Baja">Baja</option>
                </select>
                 <br>
            Tipo del Equipo<br> <select  name="id_tipo_equipo" value="<?php echo $id_tipo_equipo?>">
             <option value="CPU">CPU</option> 
              <option value="Monitor">Monitor</option>
               <option value="Impresora">Impresora</option>
                <option value="Scanner">Scanner</option>
                 <option value="Reulador">Regulador</option>
                  <option value="Teclado">Teclado</option>
                   <option value="Mouse">Mouse</option>
                    </select>
                      <br>
            Estado del Equipo<br> <select  name="id_estado_equipo" value="<?php echo $id_estado_equipo?>">
             <option value="Bueno">Bueno</option> 
              <option value="Regular">Regular</option>
               <option value="Malo">Malo</option>
                </select>
                 <br>
            Observaciones<br> <input type="text" name="observaciones" value="<?php echo $observaciones?>"><br>
            Marca<br> <input type="text" name="marca" value="<?php echo $marca?>"><br>
            Modelo<br> <input type="text" name="modelo" value="<?php echo $modelo?>"><br>
            Caracteristicas<br> <input type="text" name="caracteristicas" value="<?php echo $caracteristicas?>"><br>
            IP del Equipo<br> <input type="text" name="ip_equipo" value="<?php echo $ip_equipo?>"><br>
            identificador<br> 

                    <?php
               require("connect_db.php");

              $query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_usuarios, identificador FROM usuarios";
              $res = $mysqli->query($query);
              $option = '';
                 while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
                 {

                      $option.="<option value=\"$row[identificador]\">$row[identificador] </option>";   
                 }
           ?>

               <select name="identificador">
                  <?php echo $option; ?>
                    </select>







            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
        </form>
```

Comment: toma la primera opcion del select? introducir el codigo aqui? todas esas partes no estan en el codigo y no estas explicando cual es exactamente el problema. o como intentas guardar los datos en tu BD

Comment: Al referirme que toma la primera opción del select , toma el valor principal de cada uno de los select (Entregado,Monitor,Bueno), El restante de lineas de código ya esta insertado. Te agradeceria tus comentarios y/o recomendaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás definiendo mal el valor "por defecto" del select. Este es tu código:

```
<select name="id_estatus" value="<?php echo $id_estatus?>">
```

El tag `select` no tiene una propiedad `value` (ver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

Para preseleccionar el valor, te conviene iterar cada una de las options y compararla con el valor guardado. Mi sugerencia para tu primer `select`:

```
<?php $options = ['Entregado', 'Pendiente', 'Resguardo', 'Baja']; ?>

<select name="id_estatus">
    <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
         <?php $selected = ($option == $id_estatus) ? 'selected' : '' ?>
         <option value="<?= $option ?>" <?= $selected ?>><?= $option ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Al ejecutar tu código me sale el siguiente error:                                     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'in' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario\actualizar_equipos.php on line 145

Comment: Disculpa, fue mi error. En la línea del `foreach` está mal `$option in $options`, debe ser `$options as $option`. Corregí mi respuesta para que muestre este cambio.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias... se soluciono mi problema

Comment: Una pregunta... ya me preselecciona el dato y me lo modifica pero solo lo hace en un registro y en los demás registros existentes no los guarda.

Comment: No te entiendo... tu pregunta inicial tenía que ver con mostrar en el formulario los datos previamente guardados. Pero ahora hablas de modificar registros y guardarlos... ¿podrías aclarar la pregunta?

Comment: Es correcto, ya  me muestra ya los datos previamente guardados  eso ya lo hace. La siguiente cuestión es que si quiero modificar otro registro o linea (con todos los datos ID, etiqueta_equipo,departamento,id_estatus,id_tipo_equipo,id_estado_equipo... etc) si me respeta ya la preselección de los datos previamente guardados, pero solo guarda cambios en la base de datos la primer  registro (con todos los campos que tiene la tabla) y los demás registros no guardan cambios. ¿No se si me explique correctamente?

Comment: Lo usual es que cuando recuperas los datos de un registro, los muestras en un formulario y guardas, sólo se actualice el registro correspondiente al que previamente recuperaste... No sé cómo está diseñado tu modelo de datos pero esto es lo usual ;-) Si requieres una respuesta más elaborada te sugiero abrir una nueva pregunta donde coloques más detalles (qué quieres lograr, el string UPDATE que usas, etc). Además, así otros miembros de StackOverflow podrán ayudarte.